# Maximum based on custom order

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate highest price based on custom orders as follows (largest being first).

```
Hundred Million
Million
THO
Hundred
```

Data is as below -

```
df <- read.table(text = "Price  Unit
1445    Million
620 THO
830 Million
661 Million
783 Hundred
349 'Hundred Million'
", header= T)
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do. Is it to combine your values into one column where all values have the same unit?

Comment: Yes, right. Converting it into the highest unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to also calculate the "actual price", we can:

1. first create a dataframe of "Unit" and "Value" (for example `price_unit` in my answer).
2. Then `left_join` this `price_unit` with your original dataframe, which will match on the "Unit" column.
3. Then do the calculation using `mutate`.
4. Finally sort the column.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "Price  Unit
1445    Million
620 THO
830 Million
661 Million
783 Hundred
349 'Hundred Million'
", header= T)

price_unit <- tibble(Unit = c("THO", "Hundred", "Million", "Hundred Million"), 
                     Value = c(10^3, 10^2, 10^6, 10^8))

left_join(df, price_unit, by = "Unit") %>% 
  mutate(actual_price = Price * Value) %>% 
  arrange(desc(actual_price))

  Price            Unit Value actual_price
1   349 Hundred Million 1e+08    3.490e+10
2  1445         Million 1e+06    1.445e+09
3   830         Million 1e+06    8.300e+08
4   661         Million 1e+06    6.610e+08
5   620             THO 1e+03    6.200e+05
6   783         Hundred 1e+02    7.830e+04
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Is it possible to store units along with calculation (10^8, 10^6 ...) in 2 vectors and pass it in mutate?

Comment: I like this option. Good suggestion Benson.

Comment: @Ujjawal Bhandari see if my updated answer fits what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

First you can create a factor for your Unit variable by ordering them in the `levels` command:

```
df$Unit <- factor(df$Unit,
       levels = c("THO",
                  "Hundred",
                  "Million",
                  "Hundred Million"))
```

Then just arrange by unit, which should arrange them by smallest unit to largest:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(Unit,
          Price)
```

Which gives you this output:

```
  Price            Unit
1   620             THO
2   783         Hundred
3   661         Million
4   830         Million
5  1445         Million
6   349 Hundred Million
```